# How I can use vuex nested modules?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

As Vuex documentation says, when the project start to grow we need a way to separate state management in a more self contained and modularized scalable solution. Here namespaces come in help. Sadly at the moment of writing Vuex modules section lacks of information and examples how to effectively use them.

This is my store structure

```
store
 |- modules
   |- core
     |- country.js
     |- region.js
     |- ...
   |- roullout
     |- site.js
 |- index.js
```

Here module register `index.js`

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex'
// Core modules
import coreCountry from "@/store/modules/core/country";
import coreRegion from "@/store/modules/core/region";
// Rollout modules
import rolloutSite from "@/store/modules/rollout/site";

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    // Core modules
    core: {
      country: coreCountry,
      region: coreRegion,
    },
    // Rollout modules
    rollout: {
      site: rolloutSite
    }
  }
})
```

Now in some component I try to define actions

```js
methods: {
  ...mapActions('rollout/site', [
      LIST_REQUEST
  ])
}
```

Here the first error: `rollout/site` is not found because I guess `rollout` is a folder not a module and therefor `site` is a module and not a nested module of `rollout`.

Vuex documentation [show](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing) how to use helper to bind stuff in nested modules but doesn't show the architecture of a store with nested modules.

LIST_REQUEST is an action, come from types.js and is defined as:

```js
export const LIST_REQUEST = "rollout/site/LIST_REQUEST";
```

So in site.js module I can use as:

```js
const actions = {
    [types.LIST_REQUEST]: async ({ commit }, payload= {}) => {
        // your actions here...
    },
}
```

Since I'm using mapActions(), instead of dispatch actions like: this.$store.dispatch() I can directly do `this.LIST_REQUEST()`

```js
import {
  LIST_REQUEST
} from "@/store/types/rollout/site";

export default {
  name: "SiteList",
  created() {
    this.LIST_REQUEST()
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('rollout/site', [
      LIST_REQUEST
    ])
  }
}
```

Here another error: LIST_REQUEST() is not a function. This error come because mapAction still have to turn the action into function

How I can fix these problems with nested modules and use index.js. Maybe I have a bit of confusion in my mind, may you help to clarify these concepts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was completely misled by the question and the answer given in this post, and it probably also did so to numerous others as it had 1K views at the time of posting this.
After figuring it out on my own, I decided to post it here so that it would not waste even more people's time.

**Answer:**

use

```
modules: {
  core: {
    namespaced: true,
      modules {
        // Core modules
        country: coreCountry,
        region: coreRegion,
      }
  },
  rollout: {
    namespaced: true,
    modules: {
      // Rollout modules
      site: rolloutSite
    }
  }
}
```

(see the explanation below)

If you don't put in `namespaced: true` within your `coreCountry`, `coreRegion`, and `rolloutSite`, it will still be like `this.$store.dispatch(rollout/LIST_REQUEST)`. Put in `namespaced: true` in them if you want `this.$store.dispatch(rollout/site/LIST_REQUEST)` or, like you said, `this.LIST_REQUEST()` from using

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions('rollout/site', [
    LIST_REQUEST
  ])
}
```

For the error with "LIST_REQUEST() is not a function" maybe it's fixed by now, but I thought "rollout/site/LIST_REQUEST" was a weird name for a function. Maybe you can make defining the action work using what you have (maybe by playing around with the syntax around it if it doesn't work?)

```
const actions = {
    [types.LIST_REQUEST]: async ({ commit }, payload= {}) => {
        // your actions here...
    },
}
```

But, I would instead recommend the more common way ([Vuex guide also uses this](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html)) to define the action:

```
actions: {
  actionName (context, payload) {
    // async functions and commits here
  }
}
```

or

```
actions: {
  actionName ({ state, rootState, commit, dispatch, getters, rootGetters }, payload) {
    // async functions and commits here
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

whatever goes in the `modules: { }` is considered a **module**, which by definition (defined in the [Vuex API Reference](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/api/#modules)) is an object that is

```
key: {
  // required (can be empty)
  state,

  // optional (as denoted by '?')
  namespaced?,
  mutations?,
  actions?,
  getters?,
  modules? // **nested modules go here**
}
```

So, there are no concept of folders within modules. When you put in

```
module {
  core: { ... },
  rollout: { ... }
}
```

`core` and `rollout` will be recognized as **modules** not folders.

So, having

```
module {
  rollout: {
    site: { ... }
  }
}
```

makes no sense whatsoever. whatever goes inside `rollout` (recognized as a module) should be either `state:`, `namespaced:`, `mutations:`, `actions:`, `getters:`, or `modules:`. Nothing else.

So, to put in a module inside `modules: { }` you can either

1. directly list imported modules (keep the name from the import statement):
   `modules: { coreCountry, coreRegion }`
2. list imported modules but renamed:
   `modules: { country: coreCountry, region: coreRegion }`
3. or define a module on the spot (without importing):
   like the `core: { module content here }` and `rollout: { module content here }` in the answer I gave, or the `account` in [vuex guide](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing)

Basically, to make nested modules, you just had to put in the sub-modules within the `modules: { }` of the parent modules (can either be defined on the spot like the answer or be made somewhere else and imported) like `core` and `rollout` which are in the `modules: { }` of the root store themselves.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to nest modules and give them their own namespace, you should set the `namespaced` attribute:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    rollout: {
      namespaced: true,
      site: rolloutSite
    }
  }
})
```

When using the `mapActions` helper, you don't have to import anything other than the helper itself. Say that `rollout/site` has a method called `foo`, you should be able to just do this:

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions({ foo: 'rollout/site/foo' })
}
```

Comment: When automatically registering nested modules with a `require.context` loop and `store.registerModule`, I used an empty object as target for new nested module registrations that had no existing parent yet, but was trying to figure out why it didn't register properly. I added `namespaced: true` to that empty object, and now everything works as expected! This should be marked as answer!